# Index with Filter function is repeating first occurence because criteria has duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter, google-sheets-formula

Any help will be appreciated, I have two sets of data that has duplicates with the criteria but the column I am filtering should be unique though the criteria column has duplicates. Any idea on how i can return the values uniquely without the first occurrence repeating throughout. Also, have the result not spilling into the next row,which gives ref error
I have put a sample data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_DiSM1dF5D3FDrTytv8PLnGxKZGkXyjUbRJphRx2cvc/edit#gid=1833425825

Am expecting the result in Column C to be return row by row but the index filter function is returning and repeating the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas of how you can achieve this:

First set up a dropdown with data from range Data 1!A2:A. (I did this in Data 2!A2 in my example.)

Then use `=FILTER('Data 1'!C2:C,'Data 1'!A2:A=E2)`.  (I put this formula in Data 2!B2 in my example.) This will give the following output:

[image: Screenshot 1]

You can set up a Pivot Table.  Here is a screenshot of how it is set up:

[image: Pivot Table]

Then at the bottom of the Pivot Table editing section, I added a filter for Email Address which ignores Blank Cells.

[image: Screenshot 3]

Just two thoughts that came immediately to mind, but I am sure there are other ideas out there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that I have to select one Email at a time using the table. but am looking not less than 2000 rows of  entries.